# Counting Words from Text File into Linked List in C

Tags: c, file-io, struct, linked-list

I am new to programming in C and for an assignment for one of my classes, we are to write code that would read in a text file, put all the words in a linked list with a counter, and output that linked list into a text file.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in my below code, it only counts some of the words and seems to skip others. (I added many extra prints to try and see where the words are lost)

I then attempted to make all the words lowercase when they were added to the linked list, but that seemed to make it read even less words and I have no clue why.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct s_words {
    char *str; //word
    int count; //number of times word occurs
    struct s_words* next; //pointer to next word
} words;


words* create_words(char* word) {
    //+allocate space for the structure
    printf("%lu ", strlen(word));
    words* newWord = malloc(sizeof(words));
    if (NULL != newWord)
    {
        //+allocate space for storing the new word in "str"
        //+if str was array of fixed size, storage wud be wasted
        newWord->str = (char *)malloc((strlen(word))+1);
        strcpy(newWord->str, word); //+copy “word” into newWord->str
        newWord->str[strlen(word)]='\0';
        printf(" Create: %s ", newWord->str);
        //+initialize count to 1;
        newWord->count = 1;
        //+initialize next;
        newWord->next = NULL;                   
    }
    return newWord;
}

words* add_word(words* wordList, char* word) 
{
    int found=0;
    words *temp=wordList;
    //+ search if word exists in the list; if so, make found=1
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {

        if (strcmp(temp->str, word) == 0) 
        {  //+use strcmp command
            found=1;
            temp->count = temp->count+1; //+increment count;
            return wordList;
        }
        else 
        {
            //+update temp
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    if (found==0) 
    {  //new word
        //printf("%s ", word);
        words* newWord = create_words(word);
        if (NULL != newWord) 
        {
            //+??  Insert new word at the head of the list
            newWord->next = wordList;
            printf(" NEW WORD: %s\n ", newWord->str);
        }
        return newWord;
    }
    //return wordList; //code never gets here, just added in case of error    
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

    words *mywords;  //+head of linked list containing words
    mywords=NULL;

    FILE *myFile;
    FILE *myOutput;

    char* filename = argv[1];
    char* outputfile = argv[2];

    myFile = fopen(filename, "r");  //+first parameter is input file
    if (myFile==0) 
    {
        printf("file not opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("file opened \n");
    }

    //+start reading file character by character;
    //+when word has been detected; call the add_word function

    int ch = 0, word = 1, k = 0;
    char thisword[100];
    //ch = putchar(tolower(ch));
    //ch = fgetc(myFile);
    while ((ch = fgetc(myFile)) != EOF )
    {
        //error handling

        if (ch == '.' || ch == ' ' || ch == ',' || ch == ':' || ch == ';' || ch == '\n')  //+detect new word? Check if ch is a delimiter
        { //when above if is true, new word created in next if:
            if ( word == 1 )  //+make sure previous character was not delimiter
            {
                word = 0;
                //+make the kth character of thisword as \0
                thisword[k] = '\0';

                //+now call add_word to add thisword into the list
                printf(" Add:%s ", thisword);
                mywords = add_word(mywords, thisword);
                printf(" Added:%s\n", mywords->str);

                k=0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            word = 1;
            //make ch lowercase
            //ch = putchar(toupper(ch));
            //+?? //make the kth character of thisword equal to ch
            thisword[k] = ch;
            thisword[k] = putchar(tolower(thisword[k]));
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (word == 1) 
    {
        thisword[k] = '\0';
        //add thisword into the list
        printf("Last Word:%s ", thisword);
        mywords = add_word(mywords, thisword);      
    }

    words *currword;
    printf("printing list\n");

    //+Traverse list and print each word and its count to outputfile
    //+output file is second parameter being passed

    myOutput = fopen(outputfile, "w+");  //+first parameter is input file
    if (myOutput == 0) 
    {
        printf("output file not opened \n");
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("output file opened \n");
    }

    currword = mywords;

    while (currword->next != NULL)
    {
        //add word name then word count to file, then move to next
        fprintf(myOutput, "%s %d \n", currword->str, currword->count);
        printf("%s ", currword->str);
        currword = currword->next;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have to do the counting for all the words in the file. That means the repetition of words is also you have to count.

Comment: Why are you using *character-oriented* input (e.g. `fgetc` to read from the file), and not *line-oriented* input (e.g. `fgets` to read a line at a time), or at least formatted input (`fscanf` to read a word at a time)? You can do it with `fgetc`, but your success will be determined by covering all possible word delimiters correctly (which adds a lot of room for error) (e.g what if a word is separated by *tabs* `'\t'`?)

Comment: To assure a LETTER is lower case(the ones contained in the standard ascii table) I recommend doing a & bitwise with 32(make sure it's a letter and not another asking ). If you're unsure why this works check the difference between a and A in an ascii table.

Comment: The adjacent lines `thisword[k] = ch;` and
            `thisword[k] = putchar(tolower(thisword[k]));` are curious.  Why not: `thisword[k] = tolower(ch); putchar(thisword[k]);`?  I doubt if that is actually part of the problem, but it seems simpler to me.

Comment: @Mr.Branch: Why would you recommend that compared with using the `tolower()` (and perhaps `isupper()`) functions from `<ctype.h>`?  Especially outside the C locale, it is likely that the functions are better than masking with 32.

Comment: Although you carefully set `found = 1;` when you find the word, you don't need to do that because you return immediately.  Then the `if (found == 0)` test is superfluous — and you can lose the variable altogether, and the complex comment about not reaching the end of function.  All of which makes your code simpler — which is always beneficial.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin We have only used `fgetc` in the class to read files so far and I definitely overlooked tabs.  I will look into both `fgetc` and `fscanf`, thanks for the suggestion.  In the txt files I ran through it, there were no tabs and I am almost certain I covered all delimiters. I would still like to figure out what I did wrong here.

Comment: `while (currword->next != NULL)` should be `while (currword != NULL)`. Otherwise, you are going to miss the last word in the list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the suggestions, anything to make the code simpler.  At first I didn't have the return in that first if, thats why I had the found originally.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, didn't notice that <ctype.h> was included. Just to know is there an alternative in <stdlib.h> ?

Comment: @Mr.Branch: If `<ctype.h>` wasn't included, then it would be best to include it.  There aren't case-conversion and character classification functions in `<stdlib.h>`.  The other header that defines such functions is `<wctype.h>`, for processing wide characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure like making things hard on yourself... Your four biggest issues were **(1)** not passing the *address of* `mywords` to `add_words`, **(2)** failing to handle the New/Empty list case in `add_words`, **(3)** adding the new nodes to the head of the list, and **(4)** overwriting your list address every time you called `add_word` (e.g. `mywords = add_words...`)

Fixing each of those problems and tidying up parsing a bit, you should be able to find all of your words in your list. Look over/test the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct s_words {
    char *str;                  //word
    int count;                  //number of times word occurs
    struct s_words *next;       //pointer to next word
} words;

words *create_words (char *word)
{
    //+allocate space for the structure
    printf ("%lu ", strlen (word));
    words *newWord = malloc (sizeof (words));
    if (NULL != newWord) {
        //+allocate space for storing the new word in "str"
        //+if str was array of fixed size, storage wud be wasted
        newWord->str = (char *) malloc ((strlen (word)) + 1);
        strcpy (newWord->str, word);    //+copy “word” into newWord->str
        newWord->str[strlen (word)] = '\0';
        printf (" Create: %s ", newWord->str);
        //+initialize count to 1;
        newWord->count = 1;
        //+initialize next;
        newWord->next = NULL;
    }
    return newWord;
}

words *add_word (words **wordList, char *word)
{
    if (!*wordList) {       /* handle EMPTY list */
        printf ("NEW LIST\n");
        return *wordList = create_words (word);
    }

    words *temp = *wordList;
    //+ search if word exists in the list; if so, make found=1
    while (temp->next != NULL) {    /* iterate while temp->next != NULL */

        if (strcmp (temp->str, word) == 0) {    //+use strcmp command
            temp->count = temp->count + 1;      //+increment count;
            return *wordList;
        }
        else
            temp = temp->next;  //+update temp
    }
    words *newWord = create_words (word);
    if (NULL != newWord) {  /* insert at TAIL of list */
        temp->next = newWord; 
        printf (" NEW WORD: %s\n ", newWord->str);
    }
    return newWord;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    words *mywords;             //+head of linked list containing words
    mywords = NULL;
    char *delim = ". ,:;\t\n";

    FILE *myFile;
    FILE *myOutput;

    char *filename = argv[1];
    char *outputfile = argv[2];

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input. usage: %s ifile ofile\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    myFile = fopen (filename, "r");     //+first parameter is input file
    if (myFile == 0) {
        printf ("file not opened\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf ("file opened \n");
    }

    //+start reading file character by character;
    //+when word has been detected; call the add_word function

    int ch = 0, word = 1, k = 0;
    char thisword[100];
    while ((ch = fgetc (myFile)) != EOF) {  /* for each char    */
        if (strchr (delim, ch)) {           /* check if delim   */
            if (word == 1) {    /* if so, terminate word, reset */
                word = 0;
                thisword[k] = '\0';

                printf ("\nadd_word (mywords, %s)\n", thisword);
                /* do NOT overwrite list address each time,
                 * you must send ADDRESS of list to add_word
                 * to handle EMPTY list case.
                 */
                if (add_word (&mywords, thisword))
                    printf (" added: %s\n", mywords->str);
                else
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: add_word failed.\n");

                k = 0;
            }
        }
        else {  /* if not delim, add char to string, set word 1 */
            word = 1;
            thisword[k++] = tolower (ch);   /* make ch lowercase */
        }
    }
    if (word == 1) {    /* handle non-POSIX line-end */
        thisword[k] = '\0';
        //add thisword into the list
        printf ("\nadd_word (mywords, %s) (last)\n", thisword);
        if (add_word (&mywords, thisword))  /* same comment as above */
            printf (" added: %s\n", mywords->str);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: add_word failed.\n");
    }

    words *currword;
    printf ("printing list\n");

    //+Traverse list and print each word and its count to outputfile
    //+output file is second parameter being passed

    myOutput = fopen (outputfile, "w+");        //+first parameter is input file
    if (myOutput == 0) {
        printf ("output file not opened \n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf ("output file opened \n");
    }

    currword = mywords;

    while (currword != NULL) {  /* just test currword here */
        //add word name then word count to file, then move to next
        fprintf (myOutput, "%s %d \n", currword->str, currword->count);
        printf ("%s ", currword->str);
        currword = currword->next;
    }

    putchar ('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Test Use**

```
$ ./bin/llwordcount ../dat/captnjack.txt dat/llout.txt
```

**Output File**

```
$ cat dat/llout.txt
this 1
is 1
a 2
tale 1
of 1
captain 1
jack 1
sparrow 1
pirate 1
so 1
brave 1
on 1
the 1
seven 1
seas 1
```

*note:* for printing/output, you simply want `while (currword != NULL)` to traverse the list.

Now with that said, you should really consider using *line-oriented* input (`fgets` or `getline`) and parsing each line of data into words rather than reading *character-by-character* and looking for delimiters. It is much easier and less error prone to read/parse a line-at-a-time. Since line-oriented input is buffered, it is also a much faster read. You can read a character at a time, it is just slower and there are a lot more pitfalls along the way.

Digest the changes (commented above with `/* ... */`) and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I added a few more delimiters and tested it with several text files and it worked everytime.

Comment: Glad I could help. For one of your first lists, you were not far off. Good luck with your coding.